# Compute the expected value and variance of a discrete random variable from probability table

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation

This equation comes from Edgenuity's course of Statistics, and I am taking the course as a high school senior. I understand how to find the standard deviation.

> Standardized tests for certain subjects, given to high school students, are scored on a scale of 1 to 5. Let X represent the score on a randomly selected exam. The distribution of scores for one subject’s standardized test is given in the table.
>
> [image]

> What is the standard deviation of the distribution?
>
> A. 1.3
>
> B. 1.6
>
> C. 1.7
>
> D. 2.5

**Edit:** Firstly, I multiplied each score with its corresponding probability and then added all of these pairs together.

> $(1*0.18)+(2*0.20)+(3*0.26)+(4*0.21)+(5*0.15) = 2.95$

$2.95$ is the **mean** of the distribution.

Secondly, I found the standard deviation using the mean and the score values.

> $\sqrt{[(1-2.95)^2+(2-2.95)^2+(3-2.95)^2+(4-2.95)^2+(5-2.95)^2]/5} ≈ 1.415 $

$≈ 1.415$ is the **standard deviation** of the distribution, so the closest answer choice would be (A).

Comment: Please edit your post to show the exact calculation you performed.  I can't imagine how you got either $.041$ or $.2865$  Start by showing how you computed the mean.  If you are using an incorrect mean then of course everything else will be wrong...but no choice of mean returns values as small as you are getting.

Comment: @lulu I will edit momentarily. Just to note: I used the sample standard deviation equation, which may be the reason, like you mentioned, why the means are as small as I am getting. Would I use the population standard deviation equation then?

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  You have the exact probabilities here....there is no sample involved.  In any case, in a case where there is a sample involved, the sample variance is larger than the population variance, since $\frac 1{N-1}>\frac 1N$.

Comment: What mean are you using?

Comment: @lulu Alright. That's the error I made then. It's a simple error to divide by $n - 1$ instead of solely $n$. The mean I used is $0.2$. I added the probability values and divided the calcuation by $5$.

Comment: The mean is obviously not $.2$    The possible values are $1,2,3,4,5$ with the given probabilities.  But, if you used a mean of $.2$ you should have gotten a much larger $\sigma$.  I get $3.0479$  if I pretend the mean is $.2$

Comment: My guess (and it's just a guess since you haven't shown any calculations at all) is that you ignored the scores and just supposed you had a data set with values equal to the score probabilities.  If I repeat that, I do indeed get $.04$   But of course that has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @lulu Firstly, the mean is not "obvious" to me, which is why I submitted this question to begin with. Secondly, I will show my calculations—give me a second—however, I did mention I used the sample standard deviation equation. Apparently, I need to show what that is since it's not clear enough. And no, I didn't "ignore" the scores, I simply supposed the probabilities were in the data set as you mentioned.

Comment: I think you don't understand.  The possible scores are $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, so the mean must be $≥1$.  The probabilities of each score are $\{.18,.2,.26,.21,.15\}$ respectively.  The mean is then $1\times .18+2\times .2+3\times .26+4\times .21+5\times .15=2.95$

Comment: I obviously didn't understand then, but now I do. Your explanation makes sense—I should've multiplied the values and the probabilities.

Comment: @BruceET, indeed I was a bit flustered, as I don't work with statistics much. Undeleted it.

Comment: @Renee. After all this discussion, maybe you can revise the question to show what you now understand.

Comment: @BruceET Edited.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to write the formulas out in detail and compute the intermediate steps.

$$\mu = E(X) = \sum_{i=1}^5 ip_i\\
= 1(.18)+2(.20)+3(.26)+4(.21)+5(.15) = 2.95.$$

Using R as a calculator:

```
p = c(.18, .20, .26, .21, .15)
sum(p)
[1] 1      # validity check
sum((1:5)*p)  
[1] 2.95   # E(X)
```

$$\sigma^2 = V(X) = \sum_{i=1}^5 (i-\mu)^2p_i\\ =
(1-2.95)^2(.18) + (2-2.95)^2(.20) + \cdots + (5-2.95)^2(.15)=1.7275.$$

```
sum(((1:5)-2.95)^2*p)
[1] 1.7275
```

Alternative formula for variance:
$$\sigma^2 = Var(X) = E(X^2) - \mu^2 = \sum_{i=1}^5 i^2p_i - \mu^2\\
=1(.18)+4(.20)+9(.26)+16(.21)+25(.15)-2.95^2 = 1.7275.$$

```
sum((1:5)^2*p) - 2.95^2
[1] 1.7275
```

***Approximation by simulation:*** Simulate a million realizations of $X$ and then take
the sample mean and variance of the sample of a million, which should agree with $\mu$ and $\sigma^2,$ respectively, to a few
decimal places.

```
set.seed(2021)
x = sample(1:5, 10^6, rep=T, p=c(.18,.20,.26,.21,.15))
mean(x)
[1] 2.951815  # aprx 2.95
var(x)
[1] 1.728759  # aprx 1.7275
sd(x)
[1] 1.314823  $ close to Answer (A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that variance ($\sigma^2$) is given by:
$$\sigma^2=\sum p_i(x_i-m)^2$$ where $m$ is the mean score.
So we have, breaking the square:
$$\sigma^2=\sum {x_i}^2 p_i +\left(m^2\sum p_i\right) -2m^2$$
$$\sigma^2=\sum {x_i}^2 p_i -m^2$$
$$\sigma^2 =\sum {x_i}^2 p_i -\left(\sum x_i p_i\right)^2$$
Plug in the values, you'll get:
$$\sigma^2=10.43-8.7025=1.7275$$
So standard deviation($\sigma$)$=\sqrt{1.7275}\approx 1.3$

Clearly, your calculated value of $m$ is wrong. The correct value would be $m=2.95$

Comment: Seems a helpful approach (+1)